# Test specification for Bluetooth v4.1 Secure Connections feature

Tags: bluetooth, specifications

from where I can download test specification for Bluetooth v4.1, I'm specifically looking for Secure Connections feature. I know its bluetooth.org but not sure for the exact place.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so its here:
https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=60535

I could see what I wanted.